# Maximum number of LinkedIn connections per day?

Tags: linkedin-api

I was wondering if anyone knew what is the max number of LinkedIn connection a user can add per day?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the maximum number of linked-in request per day is 50 on single day, previous it was 300 then year by year they reduced. if you are a premium user then there is no restriction in request only in mails restriction are there. if you logged as normal user then its 50.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-get-around-new-linkedin-connection-request-limit-2021-alex-gray/ says it's probably **~100 per week**.

https://evaboot.com/blog/how-many-connection-requests-send-on-linkedin and https://expandi.io/blog/linkedin-connections-limit/ and https://www.paulgreensmspmarketing.com/the-new-linkedin-connection-request-and-what-it-means-for-msps/ seem to agree.

And the last one says there is an "ultimate cap of 30,000 connections".